# Problemas con Directivas

Tags: c#, .net, asp

Tengo una app de asp.net lo cual quiero compilar pero cuando lo hago me lanza errores de directivas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado dar un clean && build?

Comment: Ya lo hice y ni asi me dejo